# When I Formatted an external hard drive in Ubuntu the drive disappeared from the list of devices

Tags: format

I just installed Ubuntu and I connected an external hard drive.
I then went into the Files Icon and selected the external drive so I could format it.
When I began the format, the drive disappeared from my list of devices.
Is this normal? Will it reappear once the format is complete?
If so, how long should it take?
It is a 2TB drive and I selected the option to overwrite all data with 0's.
I selected ext4 file system.

Answer (score 0):

It probably unmounted so it can format. A secure erase like that on a 2TB drive is going to take a really long time, since you're essentially writing 2TB of null data to the drive. Wait a few hours and, if it doesn't reappear, open GParted  (should be pre-installed) and check for it there. If it shows there, format it in GParted.

Comment: Is `gparted` really preinstalled?

Comment: I think so. I'm pretty sure I've always been able to just open it. @A.B.

Comment: @Zacharee1: `apt-cache rdepends gparted` only lists `ubuntustudio-desktop` and `drobo-utils` (on Trusty) so it doesn't appear to be installed by default in any Ubuntu flavour except Studio.